# Best places to buy board games online?

Tags: recommendations

I have just recently found out about www.bookdepository.com and that they sell Fantasy Flight's games with very reasonable prices and ship the goods freely all over the globe. Since I live in the country that has very limited number of shops where you can buy board games and they tend to be very pricey (almost double the retail price in USA for example) - do you guys know any other online places like Book Depository which has nice deals and possibly free shipping?

Comment: Would help to know *which* country you live in :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! I'm afraid shopping and recommendation questions in general are off-topic here, so this question has been closed. Please see http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has a lot but look through boardgamegeek.com marketplace plus eBay and coolstuffinc. Try googling the game, normally there is a result that you can purchase it from.